# NSUserDefault constant not updating

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constants, nsuserdefaults

I have `NSUserDefaults` implemented in my app and the correct values persist between launches, but when referencing a constant I created the values don't update when the default values are changed during a session.

I'm certain my problem stems from using constants to reference `NSUserDefaults`, but I can see how much code it's saved me and I'd like to stick with this approach, if feasible/good practice. I'm not sure how I'd go about updating the constant for new `NSUserDefault` values. I'm not getting crashes--just stale values.

**My Setup**

**`AppDelegate.swift`**

I use `NSUserDefaults` to store some integer values in my app. In `AppDelegate.swift` I do a check to see if they're set. This works.

**`PreferencesViewController.swift`**

I have a `PreferencesVC` that I've configured that populates with the defaults and enables the user to change the default values. I put some `print` statements to verify new `NSUserDefaults` values when they're saved. This works.

**`MyTableViewController.swift`**
I declared constants on a so I can trim down verbose code.

```
// Import Statements
@import UIKit

// Constants I declare here so they're accessible throughout the app.
let kDefaultActiveTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultActiveTime")
let kDefaultBreakTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultBreakTime")
let kDefaultRounds = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultRounds")

// Class declaration
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController
```

Within my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I use the default constants to compute a time and output a string for a label on a cell. Here's the line:

```
    // boilerplate cellForRowAtIndexPath omitted
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RoutineSelectionTableViewCell

    let routine = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SavedRoutines

    // ** This doesn't update w/ tableView.reloadData()
    customCell.routineInformationLabel.text = String(format: "Time to complete - %@", formatTimeInSeconds(totalRoutineTime(routine.items! as NSOrderedSet)))
```

Here are the methods used to create the string for `routineInformationLabel.text`:

```
// Time computation methods
func totalRoutineTime(routine: NSOrderedSet) -> Int {
    var totalRounds = 0
    for item in routine {
        // get the total of rounds
        totalStretchRounds += (((item as! MyNSManagedObject).sideMultiplier?.integerValue)!) * kDefaultRounds
    }
    let totalActiveTime = totalRounds * kDefaultActiveTime
    let totalBreakTime = (totalRounds - 1) * kDefaultBreakTime // subtract 1 rest period for last item

    return totalActiveTime + totalBreakTime
}

func formatTimeInSeconds(totalSeconds: Int) -> String {
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60
    let minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60
    let hours = totalSeconds / 3600
    let stringHours = hours > 9 ? String(hours) : "0" + String(hours)
    let stringMinutes = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes) : "0" + String(minutes)
    let stringSeconds = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds) : "0" + String(seconds)

    if hours > 0 {
        return "\(stringHours):\(stringMinutes):\(stringSeconds)"
    }
    else {
        return "\(stringMinutes):\(stringSeconds)"
    }
}
```

I tried creating an observer to reload the tableView when `NSUserDefaults` are saved, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. I've also tried throwing in `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillAppear`, etc. w/o much luck.

Thank you for reading. I welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that all the constants are really giving you is a little cleaner, more readable code. I would recommend writing private helper functions in the class to do the same thing. Reading in and out of the NSUserDefaults is pretty quick and shouldn't present a problem. I also agree with the comments on the other answer, there is no need to synchronize. It's usually recommended against. Let the iOS system handle this for you. It's plenty capable of doing so. Syncronizing the defaults writes them to disk, it will do this when it is ready. Otherwise, it will keep and read the data from memory.

I don't see any glaring errors in your code shown, but my best guess is that at some point the defaults are getting updated and the constants have already been set. So basically, they'll never get set again once the class has been loaded.

To get the values in more concise, easily typed manner, consider a private function like so:

```
private func getDefaultRounds() -> Int {
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultRounds")
}
```

Which could be accessed any where in the class with just `getDefaultRounds()`

Comment: Thank you! I was looking at this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html as you posted. I like your approach. I'll circle back in a bit after I implement it.

Comment: Me right now--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS7Og1zvdy8. Thank you for such a simple solution! I'm going to explore the extension approach for learning's sake, but this gets the job done from a "here and now" standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Kyle's solution, but I experimented a little as a learning exercise and I'm throwing this up to see what folks think:

Rather than type the code repeatedly, remember what my key is, whether it's an `Int`, a `Float`, or a `Bool`, etc., I created a `Struct` to access the values:

```
struct Defaults {
    let activeTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultActiveTime")
    let breakTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultBreakTime")
    let rounds = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("defaultRounds")
}
```

When I need to access the `NSUserDefaults` values, they're updated dynamically. It seems declaring them as a constant "snapshots" them in time, but they don't update.

When I need a default and I don't want to type them, I type:

```
Defaults().rounds
Defaults().activeTime
Defaults().breakTime
```

I haven't stumbled into any "gotchas" with this approach...yet. If anyone has suggestions on how to improve on this, I'm all ears.